# Expandable listview showing all groups data in single group

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Expandable listview showing all groups data in single group and rest of two groups shown empty. Why?
I have added three different lists to a map.
I am adding a screenshot of output here:
[Screenshot of output showing all lists in a single group.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfXiu.jpg)

MainActivity code s here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
private List<String> listGroup;
private Map<String,List<Categories>> topics;
MainAdapter mainAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    expandableListView = findViewById(R.id.expand_list);
    fillData();
    mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(this,listGroup,topics);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
}

private void fillData() {
    listGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    topics = new HashMap<>();

    listGroup.add("Clothes");
    listGroup.add("Cosmetics");
    listGroup.add("Toys");

    List<Categories> clothes = new ArrayList<>();
    clothes.add(new Categories("Men"));
    clothes.add(new Categories("Women"));
    clothes.add(new Categories("Kids"));

    List<Categories> cosmetics = new ArrayList<>();
    clothes.add(new Categories("Lotions"));
    clothes.add(new Categories("Shampoo"));
    clothes.add(new Categories("Beauty Creams"));

    List<Categories> toys = new ArrayList<>();
    clothes.add(new Categories("RC Toys"));
    clothes.add(new Categories("Plastic Toys"));
    clothes.add(new Categories("Rubber Toys"));

    topics.put(listGroup.get(0), clothes);
    topics.put(listGroup.get(1), cosmetics);
    topics.put(listGroup.get(2), toys);


}
```

}

Adapter code is also attached here:

```
public class MainAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

Context context;
private List<String> listGroup;
private Map<String,List<Categories>> topics;

public MainAdapter(Context context, List<String> listGroup, Map<String, List<Categories>> topics) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listGroup = listGroup;
    this.topics = topics;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // returns groups count
    return listGroup.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // returns items count of a group
    return topics.get(getGroup(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // returns a group
    return listGroup.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // returns a group item
    return topics.get(getGroup(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // return the group id
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // returns the item id of group
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // returns if the ids are specific ( unique for each group or item)
    // or relatives
    return false;
}
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String groupi = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView heading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_parent);
    heading.setText(groupi);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Categories topic = (Categories) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);
    }

    TextView subheading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_childttxt);
    subheading.setText(topic.getChilds());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

I think now Question is clear. Please help me to find wrong thing in this code.

Comment: In the activity, all data are added to same list because all of them use **clothes.add()**.

Comment: Oh sorry! Thank you so much